# Sench Touch Examples (Some code) and Best practices apart from API documentation

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm new to Sencha Touch and I'm looking for some examples with code and best practices in implementing the touch framework from Ext JS.

Ideas and Suggestions please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SO Post: [ExtJS Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770352/extjs-best-practices)
This book is currently being written: [Sencha Touch in Action](http://www.manning.com/garcia2/)